# Creating an Oracle trigger to increment/decrement an attribute based on its uniqueness in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm making a database to model the games industry, which has two tables which look a bit like this:

```
PLAYABLE (Which games are playable on which consoles)
--------------------------------------------------
|  Game_ID (int)   | Console_Name (varchar(255)) | (both primary/foreign)
--------------------------------------------------

 CONSOLE
--------------------------------------------------
|  Console_Name (PK) |     Exclusives (int)      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The exclusives attribute gives the number of games that console, and only that console, has.

So when I insert a new tuple into the 'Playable' relation, if that 'Game_ID' already exists once, then I need to decrement the 'Exclusives' attribute with the corresponding 'Console_Name.' Similarly, if it doesn't exist, then I increment that Console's number of Exclusives.

I'm new to Oracle and here is my attempt at creating a trigger for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Exclusives_Count
    BEFORE INSERT ON Playable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        Game_Count NUMBER;
        Obsolete_Exclusive_Console VARCHAR(255);
    SELECT COUNT(Game_ID) INTO Game_Count FROM Playable WHERE Game_ID = :NEW.Game_ID;
    IF Game_Count = 0
    THEN 
        UPDATE Console
        SET Exclusives = Exclusives + 1
        WHERE Console.Console_Name = :NEW.Console_Name;
    ELSIF Game_Count = 1
    THEN
        SELECT Console_Name INTO Obsolete_Exclusive_Console FROM Playable WHERE Game_ID = :NEW.Game_ID;

        UPDATE Console
        SET Exclusives = Exclusives - 1
        WHERE Console.Console_Name = Obsolete_Exclusive_Console;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Entering this gives me 'Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors," but I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare` should be before `begin` in your code
see declaration below:

```
create table Playable(Game_ID int, Console_Name varchar(255));
create table CONSOLE(Console_Name  varchar(255), Exclusives int);
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Exclusives_Count
  2      BEFORE INSERT ON Playable
  3      FOR EACH ROW
  4  
  5  DECLARE
  6          Game_Count NUMBER;
  7          Obsolete_Exclusive_Console VARCHAR(255);
  8  BEGIN
  9  
 10      SELECT COUNT(Game_ID) INTO Game_Count FROM Playable WHERE Game_ID = :NEW.Game_ID;
 11      IF Game_Count = 0
 12      THEN
 13          UPDATE Console
 14          SET Exclusives = Exclusives + 1
 15          WHERE Console.Console_Name = :NEW.Console_Name;
 16      ELSIF Game_Count = 1
 17      THEN
 18          SELECT Console_Name INTO Obsolete_Exclusive_Console FROM Playable WHERE Game_ID = :NEW.Game_ID;
 19  
 20          UPDATE Console
 21          SET Exclusives = Exclusives - 1
 22          WHERE Console.Console_Name = Obsolete_Exclusive_Console;
 23      END IF;
 24  END;
 25  /

Trigger created

SQL> show errors
No errors for TRIGGER SCM.EXCLUSIVES_COUNT

SQL>
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, but it doesn't appear to have fixed it. I'm still getting the same warning as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: I created the trigger in sql plus and checked errors - as you can see - no errors

Comment: @EmmetOT If you created your tables with double quotes make sure you always refer to them using double quotes.

Comment: Alright, my second problem was a stupid one... The "Console_Name" attribute is actually just "Name." Sorry for wasting your time and thank you so much!